# ES6: access to inherited class'es properties and methods from the parent class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ES6 has not abstract methods or properties, but can I get some methods or properties in the parent class from inherited class?

```
class ParentClass {

    constructor(){

      ParentClass.checkClildPropertyAccessibility();
      ParentClass.checkClildMethodAccessibility();

      ParentClass.checkClildStaticPropertyAccessibility();
      ParentClass.checkClildStaticMethodAccessibility();

    }

    static checkClildPropertyAccessibility() {
        console.log(ParentClass.childProperty);
    }

    static checkClildMethodAccessibility(){
        ParentClass.childMethod()
    }

    static checkClildStaticPropertyAccessibility(){
        console.log(ParentClass.childStaticProperty);
    }

    static checkClildStaticMethodAccessibility(){
        ParentClass.clildStaticMethod()
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    constructor(){
        super();
        ChildClass.childProperty = 'child\'s Property: OK';
    }

    childMethod(){
        console.log('child\'s method OK');
    }

    // static property emulation is ES6
    static get childStaticProperty() { return 'Child\'s static property: OK even ES6' }

    static clildStaticMethod (){
        console.log('Child\'s static method: OK');
    }      
}

let childClassInstance = new ChildClass();
```

The concept is "We must to define some properties and methods in child class, however the parent class needs them to use already in constructor".

Comment: @estus, to make this question more valuable, I included 4 cases: regular property defined in child's constructor, regular method defined in child's body, static property (emulation of static property in ES6) defined in child's body and child's static method. There is no problem with using any of them outside the classes, but I want to use them in both parent class constructor and parent class body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it's possible to call methods only defined in a subclass of an ES2015 class.

```js
class ParentClass {

  constructor() {
    this.childMethod();
    this.initialize();
    console.log(this.childProperty1);
    console.log(this.childProperty2);
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.childProperty1 = 'child\'s Property: OK';
  }

  initialize() {
    this.childProperty2 = 'child\'s Property 2: OK';
  }

  childMethod() {
    console.log('Child\'s overriden method: OK');
  }
}

let childClassInstance = new ChildClass();
```

Notice `initialize()` is used to assign an initial value to `childProperty2`. Parent constructor will always run before any other code in a subclass constructor, that's why `childProperty1` isn't initialized when the console call was made. In a parent class, `this` will point to an object with the `prototype` of the subclass. *In the comments section, `Bergi` points out the practice of calling an overridden method in a parent constructor should be avoided, given the overriden method may depend on state not yet setup by the child constructor.*

And **no**, it doesn't work with *static* methods. <s>Even though static methods are copied to subclasses,</s> when you refer to `ParentClass`, you'll get the method defined there. There's no prototype chain to follow there.

**EDIT**: *clarification from comments section.*

Comment: Static methods are not *copied* to subclasses. They are inherited from the parent class object.

Comment: You should not use this `initialize` pattern. Initialisation should go in the constructor (and only there), and you should not call overridden methods before the constructor finished. If the parent constructor really needed access to the child property value, it should be passed as an argument.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your input. About the `initialize` pattern, I'm not promoting it, only stating how it works. I updated the answer for clarification.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you for the recommendation. Unfortunately I could not to make an example. As you know, in the child class `this` is not allowed before `super()`. So, I cannot pass any child's property as `super()`'s argument.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu I mean you should pass the *value* to `super()`, and the parent constructor logs it or creates the property or does whatever it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to refer current constructor in parent class as `this` in static methods and as `this.constructor` in instance methods.

This results in potential design problem, because `ParentClass` doesn't have methods and properties that are defined in `ChildClass`, and `new ParentClass` will result in error when non-existent `childMethod` is called.